# one-liner for convert hex string to char array

Tags: c++

This is probably a duplicate of [hex string to unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005669/hex-string-to-unsigned-char) but with different input

I want to read hex strings from txt file and tried to save it in array

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
0 3F 0 0 3 E0 0 1
7F 0 43 1 92 FF 0 AA
```

Expected output:

```
unsigned char array[3][8] = {
  0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
  0x0, 0x3F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0xE0, 0x0, 0x1,
  0x7F, 0x0, 0x43, 0x1, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x0, 0xAA
};
```

Note: Line ending is important. Some lines representing less than 8 bytes

I could show you 50 lines of code but that is completely garbage. My question isn't there any one-liner std::something to achieve this?

Comment: you shouldnt need 50 lines of code, but just `unsigned char x; filestream >> std::hex >> x;`. Though we can only tell you whats is wrong with your code when you include a [mcve] in the quesiton

Comment: Would [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) help?

Answer (score -1):

You can stream it:

```
std::ifstream file(…);
std::vector<char> buf;
while(file)
{
    int c;
    file >> std::hex >> c;
    buf.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: not checking results of stream operations is boringly common defect.

Comment: How do you represent line endings in your array?

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook to the chapters that explain how to use `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`, you should be able to figure out how to use this solution without "losing line endings".